# How can I store a string and corresponding tags?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a bunch of activities that are specific to age groups and genders (not trying to be agist or sexist here, just some groups are more likely to take part in these activities so I am trying to suggest them using tags)

I basically need an array that would store this information.

I want a multidimensional array that essentially looks like this:

```
["Playing Video Games", 10, 24, "male"],
["Putting on Makeup", 14, 50, "female"], 
["Sleeping", 0, 100, "both"]

["Activity name string", age lower limit, age upper limit, "genders allowed"];
```

How can I create this in iOS?

I'll be storing it in the userDefaults.

Comment: Rather than user defaults, you could use core data and store the values as attributes of an entity.

Comment: I need to save the data as it will be modified occasionally by the user

Comment: @maxhud definitely use Core Data.

Comment: You could put in a dictionary and then convert to a JSON and store as a file. But if you want to do searches, etc then CoreDate.

Comment: Core Data is a pain in the ass (to set up, to migrate, to use in multiple threads and to use in general). If you don't specifically need it, then it's much better to stick to concrete Objective-C objects (like in the accepted answer) or a Plist/JSON-like NSArray/NSDictionary structure and use the NSUserDefaults as suggested or NSCoder (or Plist or JSON...) for persistence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Objective-C` is an **object-oriented programming language**. So, you need to create a custom class called, maybe 'Person' and then add the required `properties`.

For example, the custom class's `.h` file you require will be something like :

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *activity;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *sex;
@property int ageLowerLimit;
@property int ageUpperLimit;

@end
```

Then you can manage such objects by first,

Importing this custom class in your code :

```
#import "Person.h"
```

And then creating a new `Person` type object :

```
Person *firstPerson = [[Person alloc] init];
[firstPerson setActivity : @"Sleeping"];
[firstPerson setSex : @"Male"];
[firstPerson setAgeLowerLimit : 0];
[firstPerson setAgeUpperLimit : 100];
```

To store them you could use `CoreData` or just the good old `NSUserDefaults`.

Here's how to go about the `NSUserDefaults` approach :

You first store the various `Person` objects in an `NSMutableArray`, then you synchronise the defaults :

```
NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[people addObject : firstPerson];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
[defaults setObject:people forKey:@"PEOPLE"];

[defaults synchronise];
```

To use these objects later, do this :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
NSMutableArray *savedPeople = [defaults objectForKey:@"PEOPLE"];
Person *person1 = [savedPeople objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Robert is right and u should use CoreData.
There is an nice  [Core Data Tutorial][1] which explains the basics.

WHile using UserDefaults you can store your Data in an Array

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```